# finding the login form based on content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Basically I want to find out the **login form** when there are multiple `forms` on a HTML document. My guess is as following: What if i can identify to which form strings like `'forgot your password'` or `'Remember me'` or `'keep me signed in'`  belongs then it might be login form since such strings/link appear after the password field.

Is there any way i can find out which form contains these strings/links and then use that form 's name or ID in my app ?

Update: I used following code to get form ID which contains strings 'forgot your password' but it returns nothing.

```
NSString *formID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.browser stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$('form').filter (function() {var text = this.innerHTML.toLowerCase();" 
                        "return text.indexOf('forgot your password') != -1 || "
                        "text.indexOf('remember me') != -1;}).attr('id');"] ];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var loginFormId = $('form').filter(function() {
    return this.innerHTML.indexOf('forgot your password') != -1;
}).attr('id');​
```

Or simply with `:contains`:

```
var loginFormId = $('form:contains("forgot your password")').attr('id');​
```

`:contains` selector [docs](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

> Description: Select all elements that contain the specified text.
>   The matching text can appear directly within the selected element, in any of that element's descendants, or a combination thereof. As with attribute value selectors, text inside the parentheses of :contains() can be written as a bare word or surrounded by quotation marks. The text must have matching case to be selected.

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/47V7q/1)

---

**Update:**

If you are not sure about the case of the text, you must use `filter`:

```
var theFormId = $('form').filter(function() {
    var text = this.innerHTML.toLowerCase(); 
    return text.indexOf('forgot your password') != -1 || 
           text.indexOf('remember me') != -1;
```

Comment: How to use this javascript code in UIWebView's stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: method  ?

Comment: @ManishVerma. I suggest you will ask this question with more detials in a new question.

Comment: @ManishVerma. I've no idea what that code is. I suggest you accept an answer because you got one an answer to your original question. Ask a new question.

Comment: The javascript code above is not working when used with objective-C otherwise it is perfectly running well on browser.

Comment: @ManishVerma. As I wrote you **twice**: you got an answer to your javascript question. if you have other problems\question, please ask a new question in a different thread. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
var loginForm;
$("form").each(function(){
    if($(this).text().indexOf("Remember me")>=0)
         loginForm = $(this);
})
```

Comment: That code isn't good enough. It won't work the if text is inside of a `<a>` inside of `<div>` **update:** actually your code won't work if the form has any node except of textnode! for example: `<a>` doesn't have an `indexOf` function, thus your code causes an error! **-1**

Comment: your prove is totaly wrong. i search `Remember me` not `forgot password`. But ur wright i update it with `text()` [link](http://jsfiddle.net/47V7q/3/)

Comment: I hope you're joking! **My prove is totaly wrong because I used other string(which exist in the question) to get an error with your code?! ?! ?!** I really hope you wrote that comment with a sense of humor!