# using Javascript in Objective-C

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview

How to use following javascript code in Objective-C ?

```
var theFormId = $('form').filter(function() {
return this.innerHTML.indexOf('forgot your password') != -1;
}).attr('id');
```

HOw to use code above in UIWebView's stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: method ?

I used the code above with Objective-C as follows:

```
NSString *formID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.browser stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$('form').filter (function() {var text = this.innerHTML.toLowerCase();" 
                        "return text.indexOf('forgot your password') != -1 || "
                        "text.indexOf('remember me') != -1;}).attr('id');"] ];
```

When trying to log formID , it prints nothing. Is there any syntax error in my code ?

Comment: Please refer to the related question [here][1]
this will help you a lot


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766627/uiwebview-stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring-not-changing-text-box-value

Comment: @AalokParikh to use links in comments you need to use this format `[text](http://URL)`

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea if this will work because you have only given a very small part of your problem.

Firstly, your Javascript doesn't look like it is valid.  I suspect it should be:

```
var theFormId = $('form').filter(function() {
    var text = this.innerHTML.toLowerCase(); 

    return text.indexOf('forgot your password') != -1 || 
           text.indexOf('remember me') != -1;
});
```

I added some closing brackets.

To run this Javascript using `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` you would do something like the following.

```
NSString *javascript = @"var theFormId = $('form').filter(function() { var text = this.innerHTML.toLowerCase(); return text.indexOf('forgot your password') != -1 || text.indexOf('remember me') != -1; });";

NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascript];
```

I'm not sure what you'll get in the `result` string when you run this though.

Comment: Please to go to my original question at here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069564/finding-the-login-form-based-on-content